# Cannot debug website: no symbols loaded

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, debugging

I'm suddenly getting an intermittent error with break points for my website.

I'll get the solution from svn work for a ~ a day on it and then the next day I'll insert a break point and all of a sudden I get the "no symbols message".

I've tried

1. deleting all obj and bin folders.
2. verfiying all pdb files are in datetime sync with .dlls
3. restarting VS2008
4. Even getting fresh code into my working folder sometimes works.
5. Even Reinstalling VS2008.
6. Verifying everything is in debug mode

The solution does contain other projects which I reference in the website I've applied all the above to those projects too.

Why does this happen and what can I do to resolve the problem?

This is causing me huge problems so any solution would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

Website is an ASP.Net **Website** debugging through **IIS**

Edit2:

Looking at the modules window I have less modules loaded in the broken website.

**Broke**
WebDev.WebServer.EXE    Yes No  Skipped loading symbols.
WebDev.WebHost.dll  Yes No  Skipped loading symbols.
System.Windows.Forms.dll    Yes No  Skipped loading symbols.
System.dll  Yes No  Skipped loading symbols.
System.Drawing.dll  Yes No  Skipped loading symbols.
System.Web.dll  Yes No  Skipped loading symbols.
System.Configuration.dll    Yes No  Skipped loading symbols.
System.Xml.dll  Yes No  Skipped loading symbols.

**Working**
mscorlib.dll    Yes No  Skipped loading symbols.
WebDev.WebServer.EXE    Yes No  Skipped loading symbols.
WebDev.WebHost.dll  Yes No  Skipped loading symbols.
System.Windows.Forms.dll    Yes No  Skipped loading symbols.
System.dll  Yes No  Skipped loading symbols.
System.Drawing.dll  Yes No  Skipped loading symbols.
System.Web.dll  Yes No  Skipped loading symbols.
System.Configuration.dll    Yes No  Skipped loading symbols.
System.Xml.dll  Yes No  Skipped loading symbols.
Microsoft.JScript.dll   Yes No  Skipped loading symbols.
VJSharpCodeProvider.dll Yes No  Skipped loading symbols.
CppCodeProvider.dll No  No  Cannot find or open the PDB file.
App_GlobalResources.lehpz3-i.dll    No  Yes Symbols loaded.
App_Code.uje8qrn7.dll   No  Yes Symbols loaded.
Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll   Yes No  Skipped loading symbols.
System.Data.dll Yes No  Skipped loading symbols.
System.Web.Services.dll Yes No  Skipped loading symbols.
AjaxControlToolkit.DLL  No  Yes Symbols loaded.
System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll   Yes No  Skipped loading symbols.
System.Core.dll Yes No  Skipped loading symbols.
System.Web.Extensions.dll   Yes No  Skipped loading symbols.
System.Web.Abstractions.dll Yes No  Skipped loading symbols.
App_global.asax.yoorz-jp.dll    No  Yes Symbols loaded.
*snip*
App_Browsers.wieva6wr.dll   No  Yes Symbols loaded.
System.Transactions.dll Yes No  Skipped loading symbols.
System.EnterpriseServices.dll   Yes No  Skipped loading symbols.
System.Web.Mobile.dll   Yes No  Skipped loading symbols.
System.ServiceModel.dll Yes No  Skipped loading symbols.
SMDiagnostics.dll   Yes No  Skipped loading symbols.
App_Web_yymooqyw.dll    No  Yes Symbols loaded.
App_Web__9iw0ile.dll    No  Yes Symbols loaded.
System.Web.RegularExpressions.dll   Yes No  Skipped loading symbols.
App_Web_-hwxaplp.dll    No  Yes Symbols loaded.
A_ce20f9a1_b4fe_4ebe_a615_5a0a6bd4f7cb  No  No  No symbols loaded.
M_ce20f9a1_b4fe_4ebe_a615_5a0a6bd4f7cb  No  No  No symbols loaded.

Comment: Website or WebApp project?  Debugging in Cassini or IIS?

Comment: I have this same problem; however, I'm running from my local flie system as we are not allowed to use IIS on our systems here to develop.  I'm pulling my hair out trying to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

A **workaround** for this is to use the Debug|Attach to Process option and attach to the aspnet_wp.exe process (or equivalent). It doesn't answer the question of how to fix 'standard' debugging though.

Answer (score 1):

In the Application Pools properties of the IIS Manager, try setting your Maximum number of worker processes to 1.

[image]

I am embarrassed to admit I tore my hair out on this issue for a couple days. Sometimes debugging would work and other times it wouldn't. The attach process workaround John Nolan mentioned was successful for me, and that's when I noticed I had multiple w3wp.exe processes starting up when I hit F5 to debug. Setting this value to 1 lets VS2008 pick the right w3wp.exe every time.

Answer (score 0):

In a Web site each page is typically built as its own assembly on the fly.

If you change code in such a page the source page no longer matches the existing assembly.  The breakpoint then look wierd.  Its not really a problem, when the page actually runs its rebuilt and the break points "go solid" again.

Comment: I have a BP on session_start that it doesn't hit. There have been no changes there recently.